# Is reduction potential equivalent to the ease of discharge?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis, reduction-potential

Loosely speaking, is the reduction potential equivalent to the ease of discharge in the context of electrolysis?

i.e. is it easier to discharge an ion with a higher reduction potential as opposed to one with a lower one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy is a big word.

Lower potential means it requires less energy, but that doesn't say anything about how quick the reaction will proceed.

A low potential reaction may still have slow kinetics and therefore not be "easy".

If you are comparing ions as to which will produce more product as a result of an electrochemical reaction, you need to find something with low potential and fast kinetics.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the speed of reaction, I just want to know which ions will be discharge and which won't.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Just because something is thermodynamically spontaneous, doesn't mean it will happen. It might be kinetically so slow that it appears as not happening.